# Difference between std::pair and map::value_type with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

In the following code sample I am experimenting with std::unique_ptrs. I am able to add the unique_ptr to a map as I would expect. What is surprising to me is that I cannot make it a member of a std::pair. The commented lines in the example should my trying to construct a pair that is of the same type (I think...) as my map::value_type. I am not sure why this doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <map>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

typedef std::map<uint32_t, std::unique_ptr<uint32_t>  > ntohl_map_type;
typedef std::map<uint32_t, uint32_t> u32_map_type;

void
u32_map()
{
    uint32_t key(0);
    uint32_t val(0);
    u32_map_type u32_map;

    u32_map.insert(u32_map_type::value_type(key, val));
    u32_map.insert(std::pair<uint32_t, uint32_t>(++key, ++val));

    std::cout << "u32_map: " << std::endl;
    for (auto &itr : u32_map) {
        std::cout << itr.first << " = " << itr.second << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

void
uptr_map()
{
    uint32_t key(9);
    std::unique_ptr<uint32_t> u32_uptr1(new uint32_t(ntohl(key)));
    ntohl_map_type ntohl_map;

    ntohl_map.insert(ntohl_map_type::value_type(key, std::move(u32_uptr1)));

    ++key;
    std::unique_ptr<uint32_t> u32_uptr2(new uint32_t(ntohl(key)));

    // It seems odd these don't work....
    //foo = std::pair<uint32_t, std::unique_ptr<uint32_t>(key, std::move(u32_uptr2));
    //ntohl_map.insert(std::pair<uint32_t, std::unique_ptr<uint32_t>(key, std::move(u32_uptr2)));

    std::cout << "uptr_map: " << std::endl;
    for (auto &itr : ntohl_map) {
        std::cout << itr.first << " = " << *itr.second << "\n";
    }
}

int
main()
{
    u32_map();
    uptr_map();

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
Just realized the compiler error would probably be useful:

```
error: no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::unique_ptr<uint32_t>'
  ...const, std::unique_ptr<uint32_t>(key, std::move(u32_uptr2)));
        ^                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:2554:31: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversionfrom 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') to 'pointer' (aka 'unsigned int *') for 1st argument; take the address of the argument with &
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY unique_ptr(pointer __p, typename conditional<
                          ^
/usr/bin/../lib/c++/v1/memory:2561:31: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') to 'pointer' (aka 'unsigned int *') for 1st argument; take the address of the argument with &
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY unique_ptr(pointer __p, typename...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are forgetting that the key of a map is constant (to prevent you from intentionally or accidentally messing with the internal ordering of the associative container):

```
ntohl_map.insert(
    std::pair<uint32_t const, std::unique_ptr<uint32_t>>(
//                     ^^^^^
        key, std::move(u32_uptr2)));
```

To avoid making the mistake, you could have done:

```
ntohl_map.insert(ntohl_map_type::value_type(key, std::move(u32_uptr2)));
```

The reason why the original call to `insert()` from your question's text does not compile is that since the type of the pair you are providing is *different* from the type of the pair the `insert()` is accepting (because of that `const` qualifier), a conversion will have to occur, which results in an attempt to *copy-construct* a temporary pair from the one you provide.

Copy-constructing a pair means copy-constructing its elements, and since `std::unique_ptr` is not copy-constructible, your program fails to compile.

The reason why the function using a `map<uint32_t, uint32_t>` is compiling is that `uint32_t` is (obviously) copy-constructible.

Also notice, that since C++11 `std::map` has an [`emplace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) member function (which some implementations do not provide yet, so that might be your case) that allows in-place construction of its elements:

```
 ntohl_map.emplace(key, std::move(u32_uptr2));
```

Comment: I don't think that is the issue. First you will notice I didn't have to do that in the u32_map function. Also if you notice I already have the last light (using value_type) I just thought they were equivalent statements and I don't understand why one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: @user2466803: I tried to explain that in the last edit to the answer. Please check the updated answer. Also, try what I suggest - you will see your code compiling.

Comment: Ah, the copy construction does make sense. Though your solution still doesn't compile for me. To avoid the copy construction I had to std::move temp std::pair, like so:

ntohl_map.insert(std::move(std::pair<uint32_t, std::unique_ptr<uint32_t>>(key, std::move(u32_uptr2))));

Comment: @user2466803: But it seems you are still forgetting the `const`. I tried my code before posting it and it compiled (see [this live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=a7d461c49cd9c46e651da75e6da56205-e54ee7a04e4b807da0930236d4cc94dc)).

Comment: Uh oh.... Now I am more confused :) It appears the const isn't even needed. I finally put your line right under mine and noticed the difference. I am missing a '>' for my std::pair.